# GNOME confuses names of multiple different Firefox installations

Tags: debian, gnome, firefox, desktop, icons

I use GNOME on Debian Jessie and I have different Firefox installations:

- the ESR version bundled with GNOME, which I cannot remove (as it is a dependency)
- the stable version installed from [the special Debian repo](https://mozilla.debian.net/)
- the binary files from Mozilla (installed in `/opt/firefox/...`) downloaded from their website [as explained here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/install-firefox-linux#w_installing-outside-of-a-package-manager)
- the developer edition (also as binary files) from Mozilla (installed in `/opt/firefox-dev-edition`)

In `/usr/share/applications` there are therefore different .desktop files.

```
$ ls -la firefox*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3640 Okt  4 21:29 firefox-bin.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3,6K Okt  2 08:06 firefox.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2,2K Aug 31 22:57 firefox-dev.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3,8K Sep 22 08:29 firefox-esr.desktop
```

So all files have basically this layout:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Firefox
Name[bg]=Firefox
Name[ca]=Firefox
[...some more languages...]
Comment=Browse the World Wide Web
Comment[bg]=Сърфиране в Мрежата
Comment[ca]=Navegueu per el web
[...some more languages...]
X-GNOME-FullName=Firefox Web Browser
X-GNOME-FullName[bg]=Интернет браузър (Firefox)
X-GNOME-FullName[ca]=Navegador web Firefox
[...some more languages...]
Exec=<somePath> %u
Terminal=false
X-MultipleArgs=false
Type=Application
Icon=<someIcon>
Categories=Network;WebBrowser;
MimeType=text/html;text/xml;application/xhtml+xml;application/xml;application/vnd.mozilla.xul+xml;[...]
StartupWMClass=<someStartupClass>
StartupNotify=true
```

So the ESR version has the `Name=Firefox ESR` and of course also `X-GNOME-FullName=Firefox ESR Web Browser`. The things that matter are these:

```
Exec=firefox-esr %u
Icon=firefox-esr
StartupWMClass=Firefox
```

I used this file (and the icon files provided by Mozilla) to create a desktop file for the developer edition, which looks like this:

```
Exec=/opt/firefox-dev-edition/firefox %u
Icon=firefoxdev
StartupWMClass=FirefoxDev
```

The `firefox.desktop` is created by the installation from mozilla.debian.net and is this:

```
Exec=/usr/lib/firefox/firefox %u
Icon=firefox
StartupWMClass=Firefox
```

To create a shortcut for the binary version of Firefox I copied `firefox.desktop` and named it `firefox-bin.desktop`. I changed the `NAME=` and `X-GNOME-FullName=` of the original `firefox.desktop` to distinguish it from the binary version and changed `firefox-bin.desktop` to this one:

```
Exec=/opt/firefox/firefox %u
Icon=firefox
StartupWMClass=FirefoxBin
```

Also in `/usr/bin` there are different binaries:

```
$ ls -la firefox*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 113 Sep 22 08:29 firefox
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  30 Sep 22 08:40 firefox-esr -> ../lib/firefox-esr/firefox-esr
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  22 Okt  2 08:17 firefox.real -> ../lib/firefox/firefox
```

So the issue is that **GNOME still confuses these Firefox installations**. All version are sometimes labelled as "Firefox ESR" in the top panel when I am running them.
So when I click on "Firefox" to open it for a short time in the top panel "Firefox" is shown, but a few seconds later it changes to "Firefox ESR" although I can confirm that the executed Firefox installation is *not* the ESR version.

[image: Firefox starts as "Firefox", name later changes to "Firefox ESR"]

This happens with Firefox, "Firefox Debian" and Firefox Developer Edition.
Sometimes even Tor Browser gets the label "Firefox ESR", which indicates that GNOME possibly just uses the executable name (`firefox` in this case) to determinate what program is running...

So how can I fix this?

**Edit:** For testing I created a symbolic link from `/opt/firefox/firefox ->
 /opt/firefox/firefoxbin.real` and used that "new" file in the desktop file, but this changed nothing, so the executable name does not seem to matter.

**Edit2:** Additionally I now changed the `StartupWMClass` of `firefox-esr.desktop` from `Firefox` (which was duplicate in `firefox.desktop`) to `FirefoxESR`. Afterwards now GNOME always shows me "Firefox Debian" (the name saved in `firefox.desktop`) even for all other Firefox versions, even for the ESR one. Changing the `StartupWMClass` for `firefox.desktop` did not help.

Comment: _" I changed the NAME= and X-GNOME-FullName=..."_ have you also changed `Name[de]=` (or whatever your locale is) ?

Comment: @don_crissti Now, yes. And I see that the app overview works now, but the top bar still shows the wrong name. I edited the question.

Comment: So I added a gif showing the issue and I also explained that this issue also happens with the dev edition.

Comment: You may want to specify the `--class` parameter in firefox. Take a look at my similar issue: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/313151/gnome-shell-favorites-how-running-software-is-determined/314828#314828

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I might as well answer to your question.

Try using the `--class` flag in firefox. If it matches the relative `.desktop` file, the various instances should be grouped correctly. For example, in your .desktop file:

```
Exec=firefox --class FirefoxDevel %u
```

It works for me for the same firefox executable, so as long as your versions support that flag, you should be good to go.

Comment: "as long as your versions support that flag" - Do you have any information *what* versions support this flag?

Comment: So actually your tip worked. I just got it much better when passing the `StartupWMClass` to firefox with this parameter instead of the "relative .desktop file". Afterwards this works flawless!

Comment: rugk, I think it is supported for every recent version (FFox > 3 or 4), so it should be ubiquitous :) Glad to see it was helpful, cheers!

Comment: **However** there is still one issue: When I restart Firefox from inside Firefox (e.g. when restarting after an update or add-on installation) the `--class` parameter gets missing (of course) and therefore the newly started instance of Firefox is again confused by GNOME...
So would you think this is a Firefox bug/issue?

Comment: Personally I think it's a firefox issue: it should keep the same configuration and parameters if restarted, so the `--class` should be the same.

Comment: All right, I created a bug report: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1308719