# After installing firefox nightly with flatpak when I try to run it it starts regular firefox

Tags: fedora, firefox, flatpak

I am running fedora 26 and I wanted to install firefox nightly (currently 57) alongside firefox 56 in the regular repos.

I followed the instructions on the [flatpak page](http://flatpak.org/apps.html):

> flatpak install --from https://firefox-flatpak.mojefedora.cz/org.mozilla.FirefoxNightly.flatpakref
>   flatpak run org.mozilla.FirefoxNightly

But when I do this it just starts up firefox 56 and not nightly. What could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 2):

It's just that any installation of Firefox tries to switch to the existing process unless `--new-instance` is given on the command line. As such, [GNOME confuses names of multiple different Firefox installations](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/314338/gnome-confuses-names-of-multiple-different-firefox-installations) may be a topic here, as it's also using this class name for that, I think, at least.